# Visual Studio W8 neutral language error when Create App Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8

I'm creating an app for W8 only in Spanish. Have set the NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute on AssambleyInfo.cs as "es".

When using the "Create App Package" the default language is changed just to English. I have checked that a resources.pri is created.

How can I set the app language only to Spanish when creating the App Package?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your language in `Package/Resources`?

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694075.aspx):

> Must contain a Resource element for each language that the app
>   supports. For a list of the languages that an app must support to be
>   listed in the Windows Store, see Choosing your languages. The Language
>   attribute is not critical until you submit your app to the Windows
>   Store.